# Automatic Escape character during execution is creating issue in Robot Framework

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, robotframework, pywinauto

I have a Keyword as below which will be executed for every keyword.

Below is the code

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation    Suite description
Test Template       Templete key
Test Teardown       Teardown key

*** Test Cases ***
Test case1 
    click element    auto_id=1031      control_type=Button

*** Keywords ***
Templete key
    [Arguments]     @{args}
    log     ${Healing_Result}
    run keyword if          '${HR}'=='Error' or '${HR}'=='FAIL'  fail
    ${status}     ${ErrorMessage}       run keyword if  '${HR}'=='PASS'  or '${status}'=='PASS'     Run keyword and ignore error    @{args}
                                        ...     ELSE            FAIL
    run keyword if          '${HR}'=='Error'   fail
```

In log.html

```
Templete key right_click_element, title=${printer_Name}, control_type=ListItem
click element auto_id\=1031, control_type\=Button
```

I don't understand why are we seeing `\` after `auto_id` and `control_type`

When we run the below code separately,it works without problem . But when we run with template , I am facing this issue .

```
 click element    auto_id=1031      control_type=Button
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you have defined the keyword with [variable arguments](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#variable-number-of-arguments) - `@{args}`, while probably thinking of named arguments ("keyword arguments" in python).

Thus when you pass "auto_id=1031" to it, it's just a string that happens to have an equal sign in it, not "the parameter auto_id should have the value 1031"; and also because of that it escapes the = char.

To fix it, just go with named arguments:

```
Templete key
    [Arguments]     ${kw}    &{args}
```

, and inside it:

```
Run keyword and ignore error    ${kw}   &{args}
```